# Flutter eventchannel & methodchannel performance

Tags: flutter, twilio-programmable-voice, flutter-method-channel

I'm planning on adding the native twilio SDK on my Flutter project for receiving voice calls, but I'm worried about the performance since the native code that flutter can communicate with runs on the main thread and I read that it can lead to performance issues. Is that going to be an issue and should I consider switching to native mobile development?